# Unexpected token, can't understand why

Tags: javascript

I'm new to JS and trying to creating a simple function, I get an error

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '{'
```

Which I do understand, but I can't understand why. According to the console, I have a problem in here:

```
function displayGallery(galleryName) { 

let src = './Images/' + galleryName + '/';
let imageIndex = 1;
let myGridCells = $('.foodImage');

foreach (image in myGridCells) { <--- problem here.
    let newSrc = src + imageIndex + '.jpg';
    image.attr('src', newSrc);
    imageIndex++;
}

fadeMainGrid();
}
```

But nothing seems to ne missing or extra '{', what is happening here? I tried but couldn't find an answer to why this is happening.

Comment: I believe you need `for` not `foreach`. https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_forin.asp

Comment: You can't use foreach on jquery collections like that. Use for  or $.foreach to iterate. When looking at this in dev-tools set breakpoints before your loop starts and try running in console :)

Comment: Thank you both! Shelby115 answer did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

```
function displayGallery(galleryName) { 

let src = './Images/' + galleryName + '/';
let imageIndex = 1;
let myGridCells = $('.foodImage');

for (image in myGridCells) { <--- problem SOLVED here.
    let newSrc = src + imageIndex + '.jpg';
    image.attr('src', newSrc);
    imageIndex++;
}

fadeMainGrid();
}
```

Its for not forEach when looping like this.

see here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration

Comment: `for-in` on an array sets the variable to the indexes, not the values.

Comment: `image.attr` should be `$(myGridCells[image]).attr`

Answer (score 0):

To iterate over a jQuery collection use `.each`:

```
images.each(function(i, image) {
    let newSrc = src + (i+1) + '.jpg';
    $(image).attr('src', newSrc);
});
```

Answer (score -1):

it seems to be just a simple syntax error, you can replace "foreach" with "for" and it should work the same

instead of being this:

```
foreach (image in myGridCells) {
    let newSrc = src + imageIndex + '.jpg';
    image.attr('src', newSrc);
    imageIndex++;
}
```

it should instead be this:

```
for (image in myGridCells) {
    let newSrc = src + imageIndex + '.jpg';
    image.attr('src', newSrc);
    imageIndex++;
}
```

Comment: `image.attr` should be `$(myGridCells[image]).attr`

Comment: `for-in` sets the variable to the array index, not the array element.